# C++ - Errors when trying to insert class into map

Tags: c++, class, c++11, dictionary

I have a map like so `map<string, unique_ptr<Base>> variables` and I am trying to insert data into the map `variables.insert(make_pair("foo", new Int(10)))` but I am getting to following errors:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Base>>::insert(std::pair<const char*, Int*>)’
   variables.insert(make_pair("test", new Int(10)));`

`error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
       template<typename _Pair, typename = typename`

This is my code:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Int : public Base {
public:
    Int(int i) {
        this->i = i;
    }
    Int operator=(int i) {
        this->i = i;
    }
    int i; 
};

void set() {
    map<string, unique_ptr<Base>> variables;
    variables.insert(make_pair("test", new Int(10)));
}
```

I think I need a fresh pair of eyes to look at this I'm not sure what this issue is, thanks!

**Edit**

I'm trying to make a heterogeneous map and there's a class for each data type. But I still get the same error no matter how many there are.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please. Statements outside of function bodies are invalid syntax.

Comment: A `static_cast<>`could be helpful also.

Comment: I don't get those errors from your code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/893f119bceb7514d

Comment: @aschepler for some reason removing `unique_ptr<>` makes it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This answer only applies to older versions of the main three compilers:

- GCC: Applies to 5.3.1 or earlier.  May apply to any version earlier than 6.1.0, but I haven't tested this.
- Clang: Applies to 3.7.1 or earlier.  May apply to any version earlier than 3.8.0, but I haven't tested this.
- Visual Studio: Applies to 19.00.23506.0 or earlier.  May apply to any version earlier than 19.00.23720.0, but I haven't tested this.

Conversely, if you have GCC 6.1.0 or later, Clang 3.8.0 or later, or Visual Studio 19.00.23720.0 or later, the original code should compile as is, without either of the modifications suggested in this answer.

[Thanks goes to [AndyG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27678/andyg) for pointing out that it works with later versions of GCC & Clang.]

---

The problem appears to be that it isn't creating your `unique_ptr` from your raw pointer.

If you can use C++14, try `std::make_unique()`.

```
void set() {
    map<string, unique_ptr<Base>> variables;
    variables.insert(make_pair("test", make_unique<Int>(10)));
}
```

If you can't, then try something like this:

```
void set() {
    map<string, unique_ptr<Base>> variables;
    variables.insert(make_pair("test", unique_ptr<Int>(new Int(10))));
}
```

---

Interestingly, I noticed a slight difference in how different compilers handle this.  Using the following slightly modified version of your code as a test program:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Int : public Base {
public:
    Int(int i) {
        this->i = i;
    }
    Int& operator=(int i) {
        this->i = i;

        // You forgot to return something.
        return *this;
    }
    int i; 
};

void set() {
    using namespace std;

    map<string, unique_ptr<Base>> variables;
    variables.insert(make_pair("test", new Int(10)));

    // C++14:
//    variables.insert(make_pair("test", make_unique<Int>(10)));

    // C++11:
//    variables.insert(make_pair("test", unique_ptr<Int>(new Int(10))));

    // Cheap hack for testing.
    cout << static_cast<Int*>(variables["test"].get())->i << endl;
}

int main() {
    set();
}
```

Most compilers* will fail to compile this, unless the initial line is commented out and either of the fixes is uncommented.  However, the [online MSVC compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) seemed to be able to compile it fine, without needing to uncomment either of the lines.  Curiously, the version of MSVC [available on Rextester](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) failed to compile it without uncommenting one of the two lines.

<sup>* Tested online, with [TutorialsPoint GCC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php), [MSVC 2015 online](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), and Rextester [Clang](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang), [GCC](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc), and [MSVC](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual).</sup>

Comment: The problem is not with the raw pointer. unique pointer has a constructor that takes ownership. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6402b39d91ce7328) The problem is that OP hasn't given us all the details.

Comment: @AndyG Weird.  It still doesn't work for me, apart from your link and on MSVC online.  Even tried directly copying code from your link to, for example, [Ideone](http://ideone.com/hIeTQZ), which I hadn't tried before; it gives the same error TutorialsPoint & Rextester GCC did.

Comment: That's why I suggested explicitly making the pointer, I figured this was some sort of bug most compilers, for some reason, shared.

Comment: Probably doesn't help that I only have basic understanding of smart pointers so far, so I just went with suggesting a simple solution.

Comment: I wonder what compiler exactly Ideone is using. Coliru has no trouble compiling under gcc 6.1.0 [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51881bfa08c6d274) Edit: Appears to be gcc 5.1

Comment: @AndyG I think that answers it, then: It seems that older versions of these compilers just don't support it.  Coliru has GCC 6.1.0 & Clang 3.8.0, and Cloudapp has MSVC 19.00.23720.0; it works with those.  Ideone has GCC 5.1, TutorialsPoint has GCC 5.3.1, and Rextester has GCC 4.9.3, Clang 3.7.1, and MSVC 19.00.23506.0; it doesn't work with them.  I'll update my answer to indicate that, thanks.